# How to OR a foreach looped linq lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to find in my db where an item may or may not contain particular words in its title by running a loop on an array of words. I know how to loop absolute contains on the query but i don't want to do that. here is my code:

**C#**

```
 var item = "the-batman-returns-hd-version";
 var id = 0;
        //split slug by dash into an array
        var keywords = item.Split('-'); //gives me (the, batman, returns, hd, version)


        //remove any work less than 4 chracters
        var result = _contentService.Products;
        foreach (var word in keywords )
        {
            if (word.Length <= 4) continue;
            var key = word;
            result = result.Where(c => c.Title.Contains(key));
        }

        var firstOrDefault = result.FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstOrDefault != null)
        {
             id = firstOrDefault.Id;
        }

        //loop query to search where all parts exist

        return (id);
```

The above works. But the product is called "Batman Returns" so it returns 0 because it couldn't find items that contained "hd" and "version" in anything.

is there anyway to OR the looped linq. Such as:

```
 foreach (var word in keywords )
        {
            if (word.Length <= 4) continue;
            var key = word;
            result = result.Where(c => c.Title.Contains(key) ||); //or; then loop again.
        }
```

Comment: Note that if you want the filtering to be done in SQL you're going to have to build up an expression tree that "concatenates" those conditions in a set of `OR` clauses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.Any()` method:

```
result = result.Where(c => keywords.Any(k => c.Title.Contains(k)));
```

You can further filter out words less than 5 characters like it seems you might want:

```
result = result.Where(c => keywords.Where(k => k.Length > 4).Any(k => c.Title.Contains(k)));
```

Although it would be more efficient to do it once when constructing your keywords array:

```
var keywords = item.Split('-').Where(k => k.Length > 4).ToArray();
```